# Python ctypes: when do you need to manually add b`\0` to a bytes object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, encoding, ctypes

In Python ctypes, when, if ever, do you need to manually add the null/zero `b'\0'` terminator when passing `bytes` to a function that expects null terminated data?

Specifically for the 3 cases (but others welcome)

- If the function parameter has been declared with `c_char_p` via its argtypes
- If the function has *not* had its parameter declared via argtypes
- Using `memmove`, if the interface expects a null terminated string at a memory address,

  ```py
  memmove(target, my_string.encode() + b'\0', len(my_string.encode()) + 1)
  ```

  or can you do

  ```py
  memmove(target, my_string.encode(), len(my_string.encode()) + 1)
  ```

Context: I add `b'\0'` out of paranoia in [sqlite-s3-query](https://github.com/michalc/sqlite-s3-query/blob/26037f7f305841e59a6ac96bf904750fb98fa5bf/sqlite_s3_query.py), and trying to work out if I can remove them. It seems to work fine if I do remove them, but I realise that there could just happen to be null bytes in the right places so everything just works. I'm looking for a stronger guarantee that the null bytes are there by design.

Comment: This looks like something you could easily test out provided you have this interface. Why ask? Going to self answer? I am confused.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've added more context, specifically including why I think testing isn't enough

Comment: Nothing 100% but you may take a peek into https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ctypes/test/test_unicode.py  esp.  `class StringTestCase(UnicodeTestCase):`  - they got some asserts in there that when you create a string buffer for a `func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]` the resulting buffer is 1 longer and it's reverse starts with \x00 and includes the remaining inputted chars in reverse order as well - thats about as deep as I gonna dive into that :) maybe some c / python guru can assure you better ;)

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah yes, thanks! Will change it. (Although in the case it's really used, it's just the regular hex representation of a UUID, so I think `len(my_string)` is right, albeit "accidentally")

Comment: I think you're right to worry about this.  Even if the current implementation doesn't need it, the implementation might unexpectedly change unless there's a guarantee somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in CPython, the internal buffer for a bytes object is always null-terminated and there is no need to add another one.  Whether you specify `.argtypes` or not, the pointer generated will point to this buffer.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_AsString:

> char ***PyBytes_AsString**(PyObject *o)
> *Part of the Stable ABI.*
> Return a
> pointer to the contents of *o*. The pointer refers to the internal
> buffer of o, which consists of `len(o) + 1` bytes. The last byte in the
> buffer is always null, regardless of whether there are any other null
> bytes....

Comment: I initially thought this was right, but after more testing, I'm not sure this is always the case somehow. What _should_ be a null terminated string in the format `\s3-<uuid>` sometimes has bad data after eg: `b'/s3-0aab7caf-bed9-4353-b652-b04ac16d379eifierVGoogle^com\xf0\xf4.\n\x01`. This doesn't happen if I manually add a null byte.

Comment: @MichalCharemza edit your question with an [mcve]. In a memmove, for example you do have to copy `len(s)+1`. The null byte is always at the end of the internal buffer but isn’t accounted for in the length of the string.

Comment: Ignore me... I was printing a copied version of the string that didn't copy the null byte